# Python urllib2 URLError HTTP status code.

Tags: python, exception, urllib2

I want to grab the HTTP status code once it raises a URLError exception:

I tried this but didn't help:

```
except URLError, e:
    logger.warning( 'It seems like the server is down. Code:' + str(e.code) )
```

Comment: Strange. Can you paste the code you use for opening the url?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You shouldn't check for a status code after catching `URLError`, since that exception can be raised in situations where there's no HTTP status code available, for example when you're getting connection refused errors.

Use `HTTPError` to check for HTTP specific errors, and then use `URLError` to check for other problems:

```
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(url)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.code
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.args
```

Of course, you'll probably want to do something more clever than just printing the error codes, but you get the idea.

Comment: To be 100% safe, you might also want to check for ValueError as urllib2.urlopen will throw ValueError exception when the url entered is invalid or blank.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are getting this error. If you are using `urllib2` this should help:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import URLError

try:
    urllib2.urlopen(url)
except URLError, e:
    print e.code
```

Comment: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'code'.
It is better to use e.reason.